MYSQL Server connection with Apache Netbeans
I recently downloaded MYSQL community containing server and workbench to use in my project i used JDBC driver to connect to Apache Netbeans 22 which worked perfectly until it has can't connect to  MYSQL and when i open the server it says that it unable to connect to Localhost  3306. what can I do tosolve this please
I tried deleting the JDBC driver and downladed it again but when i test connection it says that no connection failed followed online tutorials but i can't understand them[this is what happens when i enter localHost server it does'nt require password but bring me to this page]

The screenshot indicates mysql is not running.

Your mysql doesn't seem to be starting. You should start mysql before connecting. You can start mysql with cmd search services.
enter image description here
